# I'm making a snake game in Unity, but I coudn't figure out a way to do a curved tail

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a snake game, also I want to make the tail smooth not grid based.

I did the head with the lerp and made another gameobject at the end that follows the last tail.

My tail movement system is after the head moves the last tail got the head's position.

[the snake sprites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFwRQ.png)

I tried raycasting and when ever the specific raycast got alerted like when left and up ray is true.

Make the sprite left_up.sprite thing but it didn't work if come up with any idea I'm looking for possible ways not the 100% solution (my English is bad sorry for that)

The code if you want to see (I tried to add the tail to a parent)

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TailScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Sprite leftup;
    [SerializeField] Sprite rightup;
    [SerializeField] Sprite leftdown;
    [SerializeField] Sprite rightdown;
    [SerializeField] Sprite staight;
    [SerializeField] Sprite upstaight;

    public SpriteRenderer spriteRenderr;

    [SerializeField] LayerMask tailLayer;

    private RaycastHit2D leftRaycast;
    private RaycastHit2D rightRaycast;
    private RaycastHit2D upRaycast;
    private RaycastHit2D downRaycast;

    private bool leftis = false;
    private bool rightis = false;
    private bool upis = false;
    private bool downis = false;

    private void Start()
    {
    }

    void Update()
    {
        leftRaycast = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.left, transform.position.x + 1f, tailLayer);
        rightRaycast = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.right, transform.position.x + 1f, tailLayer);

        upRaycast = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.up, transform.position.y + 1f, tailLayer);
        downRaycast = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.down, transform.position.y + 1f, tailLayer);

        if (leftRaycast.collider != null)
        {
            leftis = true;
        }
        else if (upRaycast.collider != null)
        {
            upis = true;
        }
        else if (downRaycast.collider != null)
        {
            downis = true;
        }
        else if (rightRaycast.collider != null)
        {
            rightis = true;
        }

        if (leftis && rightis)
        {
            spriteRenderr.sprite = staight;
            Debug.Log("left and right");
            leftis = false;
            rightis = false;
        }
        else if (downis && upis)
        {
            spriteRenderr.sprite = upstaight;
            Debug.Log("down and up");
            upis = false;
            downis = false;
        }
        else if(leftis && upis)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.forward * 0);
            spriteRenderr.sprite = leftup;
            Debug.Log("left and up");
            leftis = false;
            upis = false;
        }
        else if (rightis && upis)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.forward * 0);
            spriteRenderr.sprite = rightup;
            Debug.Log("right and up");
            upis = false;
            rightis = false;
        }
        else if (leftis && downis)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.forward * 0);
            spriteRenderr.sprite = leftdown;
            Debug.Log("left and down");
            leftis = false;
            downis = false;
        }
        else if (rightis && downis)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.forward * 0);
            spriteRenderr.sprite = rightdown;
            Debug.Log("right and down");
            downis = false;
            rightis = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that in the end it will still look like tile based. Why you want to do tiling but without the grid?

Comment: you only showed how the sprites are switched ... not how you are moving them which seems what your main question is about (?)